# Login Process , OAuth (facebook,twitter) and also "Normal Way" login

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, facebook-login

I am developing a web apps that require user to login.

How to let my user (first time) login with their Facebook or Twitter account but also let them directly register an account in my apps. Something like hybrid login system.

If the user have directly registered an account, how to allow them to connect to their Facebook or Twitter account, then let them login using those connected Facebook or Twitter account.

Any tutorials, articles or keywords could allow me to do more research ?

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook:
You can use [PHP API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) and thy to get user. [Get user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/)

```
    $facebook = new Facebook($config); // Get the Facebook class

    try{
        $facebookId = $facebook->getUser();
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        $facebookId = false;
    }

    if (!$facebookId) {
        /**
         * Redirect to authorization
         */
        $redirect = 'THIS_URL'; // FB will redirect here after auth.
        $scope = 'publish_stream, email';

        // Redirect user to URL provided by Facebook class
        return $this->redirect($facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => $redirect, 'scope' => $scope)));
    }

    // Here you can find that user by $facebookId and authorize him or register him.
```